# Here's Bub. A not-so-world-class soccer player

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

This is Bub. Bub is a soccer player. However, he's not a very good one. He still can't kick the ball to the net! (If you haven't noticed, `@` is the ball.

```
                                                       _____
                                                      |     \
  O                                                   |      \
 \|/                                                  |       \
  |                                                   |  net   \ 
 / ─   @                                              |_________\
```

To help develop his skills, he's developed a system to help evaluate his performance when he kicks the ball. He's called it the "10 point system."

However, he doesn't know what he needs to do to achieve *x* number of points. You need to help him visualize where the ball will be, so that he can set an expectation of how many points he wants to get. There are 10 points per round that he can achieve.

Therefore, this is your challenge.

Given a number *x*, the number of points Bub gets, output the location of the ball on the field. Here are some helpful markers:

- Bub is exactly 50 spaces away from the net.
- For each point that Bub gets, the ball moves 5 spaces closer to the net. Therefore, if Bub gets 3 points, the ball is 35 spaces away from the net.
- For every 3 points that Bub gets, the ball begins to move in the air! It moves one space up.
- If the number of points Bub gets would move the ball behind the net, you can put the ball anywhere inside the net.

Remember, you need to draw Bub, the ball, and the net.

To get you started, here's an example:

#### Number of Points: 5

```
                                                       _____
                                                      |     \
  O                                                   |      \
 \|/                                                  |       \
  |                          @                        |        \ 
 / ─                                                  |_________\
```

Standard rules apply. Code with the lowest number of bytes wins! Happy golfing!

Comment: Can we count that character as one byte?

Comment: Do we have to output the trailing spaces exactly as given, or can we print extra?

Comment: @edc65 I take it as "move the ball one position up for each 3 points"

Comment: @Pietu1998 Exactly as given.

Comment: @LeakyNun Which character? If we're talking the unicode character, yeah, I'll let it be one byte. Sorry for answering your questions late, I was sleeping :P

Comment: If `There are 10 points per round that he can achieve`, why sould we care about n>10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>106</s> 91 bytes

Run-length encoding, followed by internal encoding.

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 4a 63 72 58 2e 22 30 41 01 b6 07 31 11 af 55 c5 JcrX."0A...1..U.
0000010: 16 6f 93 4f ea 90 6b 39 f6 e0 dc 81 43 9d 01 f7 .o.O..k9....C...
0000020: 36 93 ee 4c c8 fa a5 28 70 22 6d 43 2b 35 38 64 6..L...(p"mC+58d
0000030: 38 22 0a 20 2f 4f 5c 5c 5f 7c 2d 22 39 62 6a 58 8". /O\\_|-"9bjX
0000040: 4a 4b 2d 35 2f 68 53 2c 54 51 33 58 40 4a 4b 68 JK-5/hS,TQ3X@JKh
0000050: 53 2c 35 38 2b 34 2a 35 51 5c 40                S,58+4*5Q\@
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JcrX.%220A%01%C2%B6%071%11%C2%AFU%C3%85%16o%C2%93O%C3%AA%C2%90k9%C3%B6%C3%A0%C3%9C%C2%81C%C2%9D%01%C3%B76%C2%93%C3%AEL%C3%88%C3%BA%C2%A5%28p%22mC%2B58d8%22%0A+%2FO%5C%5C_%7C%E2%94%80%229bjXJK-5%2FhS%2CTQ3X%40JKhS%2C58%2B4%2a5Q%5C%40&input=12&debug=0)

Replace the Unicode character `─` (U+2500) as a single hyphen.

Comment: Oh dear. There's an extra space on the bottom most line of your output! And the ball goes behind the net, not inside! Try an input of 12 and you'll see!

Comment: Oh yes, the line is Unicode. I love the answer. Kudos for being first!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 189

```js
f=n=>"       o \\|/ | / -".match(/.../g).map((v,r)=>(v=[...v+' '.repeat(50)+'| '[+!r]+' _'[+(!r|r>4)].repeat(r+4)+'\\_'[+!r]],y-r?0:v[x]='@',v.join``),n<11?0:n=11,x=3+n*5,y=5-(n/3|0)).join`
`
```

**Test**

```js
f=n=>"       o \\|/ | / -".match(/.../g).map((v,r)=>(v=[...v+' '.repeat(50)+'| '[+!r]+' _'[+(!r|r>4)].repeat(r+4)+'\\_'[+!r]],y-r?0:v[x]='@',v.join``),n<11?0:n=11,x=3+n*5,y=5-(n/3|0)).join`
`
var n=0

setInterval(function(){
  N.textContent=n,O.textContent=f(n),n=(n+1)&15
},1000)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre><span id=N></span>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work for me. I just get an error saying "Script error."

Comment: @Zizouz212 what browser? Is it ES6 compatible? https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @edc65 Ah. My fault then. I use Safari :/